# Application.Wait and AppActivate not working properly with SendKeys

Tags: vba, excel

I have to sendkeys to notepad

having th Notepad already opened the code is the following

```
 AppActivate "Blocco Note"
 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
 Call SendKeys("sdfse", True)
....
 Call SendKeys("sdfse", True)
```

I even tried with Applicatio.OnTime

```
Sub test1
    AppActivate "Blocco Note"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "test2"
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Call SendKeys("sdfse", True)
    ....
    Call SendKeys("sdfse", True)
end Sub
```

the problem is that it waits 2 seconds and only then it activate the notepad so the first sendkeys does not work

could you pleas help me?

thank you very much

**EDIT: I am doing some tests and I noticed that the code works only when whe notepad is not minimized.**

Comment: Why not just write directly to the .txt file instead?  SendKeys to Notepad seems like overkill of epic proportions.

Comment: this is just a test .. I need to uderstand why application.ait doesn't work properly

Comment: Put in a `DoEvents` call right after `AppActivate` to let Excel handle the message pump.

Comment: not working with doevents

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) 'make the application wait for 2 seconds.
```

Found at the MSDN site here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx

```
Application.SendKeys("Keys")
```

Found at the MSDN site here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx